# Direction of Angular Acceleration

Tags: rotational-kinematics

[image]

The axes: z+ = directly up, x+ = along axle, towards the right, y+ = perpendicular to the axle, into the page

Solving for the instantaneous angular acceleration of the flywheel on the axle indicates that its direction is in the negative y direction (perpendicular to the axle, out of the page). Is there an intuitive way of understanding why it is so?

Comment: is the velocity of the plate changing?  BTW some of your directions are confusing.

Comment: The magnitude of angular velocity of both spinning objects does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the acceleration accounts only for the change of the direction of angular velocity vector, so it should be orthogonal to angular velocity. Angular velocity of the wheel is directed in the negative $x$ direction, and turning *toward* us, that is, in the negative $y$ direction, so the angular acceleration is directed in the negative $y$ direction.

A good analogy is how the linear acceleration of body moving in circle is directed toward the center of the circle.